# Email rendering on AngularJS server

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, email

I have an AngularJS 1.x app and a node.js server which needs to send emails occasionally.  The emails require that horrible old-style HTML and CSS to make them render nicely in the major email clients, but they also share much data and logic that is already there in the Angular app.

I could use Jade, Pug, Mustache, doT, etc... as an Express templating engine, but it seems to me, `ng-repeat`, `ng-if` would also do the job without having to learn another framework and syntax.

What approaches do people recommend for using Angular server side to render emails?

First off, is there a email client rendering problem with custom elements and attributes (eg `<div ng-if="..." ... ></div>`) that will be left over in the email?

If not...

What I really want is some engine that takes a template with Angular markup as an input, processes it within the context of some Angular controller or component, and produces the finally rendered HTML as an output.

Here's some approaches I'm considering

- Use Angular 1.x with jsdom or the like. Something like [angular-on-server](https://github.com/runvnc/angular-on-server/wiki/Running-AngularJS-on-the-server-with-Node.js-and-jsdom) or [ng-node-compile](https://github.com/MoLow/ng-node-compile).
- Use Angular 2.x. [angular2-universal-starter](https://github.com/alexpods/angular2-universal-starter) is the closest example I've found, but I can't quickly understand how that works and whether it fits my use case.

NOTE: this is not the usual use case that uses Angular server-side to initial page render faster or for SEO purposes.  I have no need, after the email is rendered, to run Angular on the "client side" (you can't even do that in emails).

Comment: can you post your html, because not every angular templates can run in server side.

Comment: but I still think you need to render template in client side, and send html back to server to do the job.

Comment: @YOU, sorry, my question was asked ahead of writing any template code so I don't have any to post, but mostly I'll use `{{}}`, `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` (or equivalents in Angular 2).

Comment: ng-if, ng-repeat, and `{{}}` is easy, but if you have custom directive or angular controllers have to run (which may in turn have $http calls, and services etc.), then you need full blown server side angular js rendering.

Comment: @YOU OK cool.  Have you got any experience with what gmail, hotmail, outlook etc will do with custom HTML tags and attributes, of which there are usually many in Angular?

Comment: I do generate html templates with angular at client for email marketing guy at work, but I have to use native html tags and inline styles, and strip unnecessary tags, attributes after page is rendered. They are in different route, difference controllers, except they share same data from server.

Comment: @YOU yes, I am beginning to think that the code overlap in my case won't be so great either, and all the parsing and stripping after render seems like I'm using the wrong tool for the job.  Thank you for your comment.